# pytest-cov - Don't count coverage for the directory of integration tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, coverage.py

I have the following directory structure:

```
./
    src/
    tests/
        unit/
        integration/
```

I would like to use pytest to run all of the tests in both `unit/` and `integration/`, but I would only like coverage.py to calculate coverage for the `src/` directory when running the `unit/` tests (not when running `integration/` tests).

The command I'm using now (calculates coverage for all tests under `tests/`):

```sh
pytest --cov-config=setup.cfg --cov=src
```

with a setup.cfg file:

```
[tool:pytest]
testpaths = tests

[coverage:run]
branch = True
```

I understand that I could add the `@pytest.mark.no_cover` decorator to each test function in the integration tests, but I would prefer to mark the whole directory rather than to decorate a large number of functions.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to get coverage report if I am having my integration tests as a separate project? If I take your example structure, my integration tests are on the root folder.  In this case how can we get the coverage report?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach markers dynamically. The below example does that in the custom impl of the [`pytest_collection_modifyitems`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) hook. Put the code in a `conftest.py` in the project root dir:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pytest


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    no_cov = pytest.mark.no_cover
    for item in items:
        if "integration" in Path(item.fspath).parts:
            item.add_marker(no_cov)
```